# magento admin controller action showing page 404

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created module but its controller action not working.
At admin i set form action to my cotroller method action like **http://localhost/icebox/index.php/admin/customtab/index** But it show page 404.

Please suggest me why admin Controller action not working, Where i did mistake.
Thank you

Here is my Config.xml file script

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Icebox_Mytabs>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Icebox_Mytabs>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mytabs>
                <class>Icebox_Mytabs_Block</class>
            </mytabs>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <mytabs>
                <class>Icebox_Mytabs_Model</class>
            </mytabs>
        </models>
    </global>
    <admin>
         <routers>
            <mytabs>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Icebox_Mytabs</module>
                    <frontName>icebox_mytabs</frontName>
                </args>
            </mytabs>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mytabs>
                    <file>mytabs.xml</file>
                </mytabs>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <fishpig_save_product_data>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customtab/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </fishpig_save_product_data>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: add your code of `config.xml` and controller file

Comment: Can you show us the code and module structure, also assuming everything is already there and correct have your cleared your magento config cache (or logged out and back in again)

Comment: Hello @Piyush, DanCarlyon, Sumil   Please look into my Config.xml file

Comment: your url should be like this -
 `http://localhost/icebox/index.php/icebox_mytabs/adminhtml_customtab/index`

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. This url showing page 404.   Is there any changes in XML file

Comment: Any body please look into this

Answer (score 0):

Please check my module configuration for the admin controller
**config.xml**

```
<config>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <resturant>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Sanghavi_Resturant</module>
                <frontName>resturant</frontName>
            </args>
        </resturant>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <resturant module="resturant">
            <title>Resturant</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="resturant">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>resturant/adminhtml_resturant</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </resturant>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Sanghavi_Resturant>
                        <title>Resturant Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    </Sanghavi_Resturant>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <resturant>
                <file>resturant.xml</file>
            </resturant>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Create controller **ResturantController.php**

```
class Sanghavi_Resturant_Adminhtml_ResturantController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action {
public function indexAction() {
    $this->_initAction()
        ->renderLayout();
}}
```

Create admin layout file **resturant.xml**

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<resturant_adminhtml_resturant_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="resturant/adminhtml_resturant" name="resturant" />
    </reference>
</resturant_adminhtml_resturant_index>
```

Comment: Hello Sunil, I have added on Config.xml file script in Question please have a look

Comment: Follow my comment you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any ACL in your config under the `adminhtml` node, this *could* be causing a problem, add that clear your Magento config cache see if it shows,

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    < mytabs >
                                        <title>Icebox Mytabs - All</title>
                                    </mytabs >
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Also i believe your admin url should be something like: `http://localhost/index.php/admin/icebox_mytabs/index`

Comment: Hello Dancarlyon, I added it but it is not working. Please suggest me what issue may be.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your system/exception logs?